# Copy the contents of array or memory block to another specific type, using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, copymemory

I need to copy the contents of an array to a variable of another type, as in the example below, but I can not find a solution. 
Note: I need this routine to work on Android with Delphi 10.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
type TMyType = packed record
  Var_1: Byte;
  Var_2: Byte;
  Var_N: Byte;
end;

Var aa: TMyType;
    vArr: TByte;
begin

  vArr := [1, 2, 3];

  // Copy vArr content to "aa" like this
  aa :=  @vArr;

  // aa.Var_1 = 1;
  // aa.Var_2 = 2;
  // aa.Var_N = 3;
```

Comment: `CopyMemory(@aa, @vArr[0], Min(SizeOf(aa), Length(vArr)));` (assuming `vArr` is `TBytes`)

Comment: @Victoria, In Delphi 10.2 this `CopyMemory` function apparently does not exist. Also, if I'm not mistaken, it's a unique function of the Windows API and I forgot to quote in my question that it needs to work also on Android. Now I have corrected my question. Thank you!

Comment: Use `Move(vArr[0], aa, Min(SizeOf(aa), Length(vArr)));` then.

Comment: @wBB `CopyMemory()` is indeed a Win32 API function, so it only works on Windows. For a cross-platform solution, use the RTL's `Move()` function instead.

Comment: @Victoria, I don't know what I might be doing wrong, but the content of `vArr` isn't being copied to` aa` (other values are copied). Another thing is `SizeOf (vArr) = 4`, when it should be 3 ... I also tried to use `array of Byte` and `SetLength (vArr, 3)` instead of `TBytes` to declare the array, but both results were wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Vitória's solution was the one I used:

```
Move(vArr[0], aa, SizeOf(aa));
```

The corrected code looks like this:

```
type TMyType = record
  Var_1: Byte;
  Var_2: Byte;
  Var_N: Byte;
end;

Var aa: TMyType;
    vArr: array of Byte;
begin
   aa.Var_1 := 0;
   aa.Var_2 := 0;
   aa.Var_N := 0;

   vArr := [3, 4, 5];

   // Where "vArr[0]" is the pointer to the first memory location to be copied.
   // SizeOf must to be used for records/data structures and Length for arrays.
   Move(vArr[0], aa, SizeOf(aa));

// Result:
//   aa.Var_1 = 3
//   aa.Var_2 = 4
//   aa.Var_N = 5
```

Comment: This answer seems mostly to discuss the mistakes you made when copying code from a comment. You discuss all these mistakes, none of which can be found in that comment. Why not just answer the question.

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan. I just intended to help other people understand where I made my mistake so that no one would make the same mistake again. That is why I explained my mistakes.

Comment: This isn't a site to tell stories about all the mistakes you made. It's a simple question and answer. Why not just answer the question.